# Do the Sith identify young potentials?

Tags: star-wars, sith, star-wars-legends

The Jedi Council identifies young potentials in the Republic systems, and recruit them for training...

> **Qui-Gon:** Had he been born in the Republic, we would have identified him early...

How about the Sith? Do they just focus in converting existing Jedi to the Dark Side, or is there any occurence of a Sith finding a young potential and taking him as an apprentice?

Comment: In ancient times, yes (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_academy). In recent time, no

Comment: Plagueis discovered a list of Force-sensitives whom Venamis was scouting as potential apprentices. He sought them out himself, and took an interest in the teenage son of a nobleman on the planet Naboo...named Palpatine....After realizing the boy's Force-sensitivity and cultivating his interest in the dark side's power, Plagueis manipulated him into murdering his own family, thereby initiating him into the fold of the Sith. Darth Plagueis dubbed Palpatine Darth Sidious and began the youth's training"

Comment: If you talk about the movies as cannon, Yoda says "Always two there are, no more, no less: a master and an apprentice."  While there must be some sort of identification, I would think that process is much different then the Jedi Council's process.

Comment: They pretty much have to. Trying to convert an existing Jedi or even Padawan contains the risk of backfiring tremendously. Even if they are likely candidates, there is a chance that they turn at the last moment and reveal the existence of the Sith/Dark Force User to the Council. Then they would be on the fast track to become the Republic's Most Wanted (or at least the Jedi Council's Most Wanted). Recruiting yet undiscovered potential is much stealthier.

Comment: @Sebastian_H: Excellent point. It should be noted that Sidious went on to take three separate apprentices who had trained as Jedi - Vergere, Tyrannus, Vader - only *after* he became Supreme Chancellor, and no longer had time to seek out his own potentials. He also had the power to have saved himself if the Jedi turned on him by that point.

Answer (score 9):

The Sith would be foolish to recruit only from existing Jedi.

At the time of the movies the Sith were in hiding and could not openly recruit like the Jedi. Still, the Jedi could not identify every Force-sensitive individual and the Sith could recruit from them.

The most notable examples from the timeframe of the movies are:

1. [Darth Sidious](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine#Darth_Plagueis_and_Darth_Sidious) (Sheev Palpatine) -- nobleman and politician from Naboo who was never a Jedi but recruited by his master Darth Plagueis.
2. [Darth Maul](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Maul/Canon#Early_life) -- Nightbrother from Dathomir who was recruited by Darth Sidious while still a boy.

Note: some of the backstory for Sidious and Maul comes from Legends, but their recruitment is hinted at by the movies. For example, the Jedi weren't even aware of the existence of Maul, so he obviously had to be recruited independently by the Sith. Similarly, Palpatine could never have been a Jedi since he was an adult politician at the time of the movies.

---

The Legends novel *Darth Plagueis* claims that it is a dark side ability to sense the midi-chlorians in Force-sensitive individuals, and that this ability allowed the Sith to recruit for many generations. Quoting the book on p. 44:

> The Jedi routinely performed blood tests to verify the midi-chlorian counts of prospective trainees, but Plagueis had passed beyond the need for such crude measurements. He could not only sense the strength of the Force in another but also perceive the midi-chlorians that individualized Forceful beings. It was that dark side ability that had allowed generations of Sith to locate and initiate recruits.

Reaching farther back into Legends (and in a much earlier timeframe in the *Star Wars* universe), [Darth Bane](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane/Canon) recruited the young girl who would eventually become [Darth Zannah](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Zannah#Touch_of_the_dark_side). She was in the process of [beginning Jedi training](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Zannah#Jedi_recruit) but could not be considered a Jedi. Darth Bane instituted the [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two/Canon) (which obviously limited Sith recruitment significantly) but before him the Sith maintained several [academies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_academy) throughout their history. [Bane himself was trained in the Korriban Academy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane#Training_on_Korriban) along with some trainees who had been recruited by the Sith at a much younger age.

Note: Again, Bane himself is canon but his backstory which covers his Sith training and recruitment of Darth Zannah is from Legends.

Comment: -100 for using that ridiculous first name for Palpatine in public :)

Comment: @DVK I don't like it, either. It figures that of all the novels reduced to Legends the novel that gave him that stupid name was not one of them.

Comment: Wait, Palpy was from Naboo?  Wouldn't he then be the senator and not Queen/Ex Queen Amidala?

Comment: @Oldcat He was the Senator from Naboo during Episode I (while Amidala was queen). He was then elected to Supreme Chancellor. When Amidala's reign as queen ended she became the new Senator from Naboo.

Answer (score 0):

No 
because they don't need to. The only reason the Jedi do is so that they don't have any exposure to the dark side and can train to defend against that from an early age. But the Sith for the most part preferred to choose  apprentices who are in there late teens and early 20's for the very reason that the Jedi Find force users at infancy. because they would have had enough exposure to darkness to be quit powerful in the dark side. Of course there are exceptions to every rule such as Darth Maul who was raised by Palpatine from infancy and Darth Plaugies who started his training at the age of 8. But the average Sith apprentice would start training at around 16-22.

Comment: Vader found Starkiller as a toddler and raised him as an apprentice.

Comment: 1.Starkiller was at least 11when Vader found and trained him 2.He was never a full Sith 3. In my answer I stated that there are exceptions to every rule and even listed some, and 4. Starkiller isn't cannon and since his story takes place during the same time as Star Wars Rebels and contradicts it then it can't be counted.